# Can't establish a lower bound on a supremum

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have a sequence of functions $f_{k,j}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f_{k,j} = k^{\frac{1}{p}}\chi_{(\frac{j-1}{k},\frac{j}{k})},$$ 
for all $k\geq 1,1\leq j\leq k$.

This serves as an example of a sequence that converges to $0$ in measure, but not in $L^{p,\infty}$.

---

It is easy to verify convergence in measure, but I am trying to check that $\|f_{k,j}\|_{p,\infty}\geq 1$ for all $k\geq 1$.  The following proof is given which I cannot follow:

(Take $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure.)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\|f_{k,j}\|_{p,\infty} &=& \sup_{\alpha > 0}\alpha\cdot\mu(\{x\in [0,1] : f_{k,j}(x) > \alpha\})^{\frac{1}{p}}\text{, (by definition)}\\
&\geq& \sup_{k\geq 1}\frac{(k - \frac{1}{k})^{\frac{1}{p}}}{k^{\frac{1}{p}}}\\
&=& 1
\end{eqnarray*}

---

I am stuck trying to verify the $(\geq)$ step.  At first I thought it was just restricting the supremum to the range of $k\geq 1$ which is more specific than $\alpha > 0$, but $k$ is already being used as an index.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just note: If $\alpha>k^{1/p}$, then  $ \mu(\{x\in [0,1] : f_{k,j}(x) > \alpha\}) =0$. If $\alpha\le k^{1/p}$, then  $ \mu(\{x\in [0,1] : f_{k,j}(x) > \alpha\}) =1/k$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't read carefully. What I mentioned in my first comment implies the norms are bounded below by $1$. What you have written above   perplexes me as well ...

Comment: Well then I feel at least a little bit better for my confusion.  Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David Mitra pointed out
$$
\mu(\{x\in[0,1]:f_{k,j}(x)>\alpha\})=
\begin{cases}
0\quad&\text{ if }\quad \alpha>k^{1/p}\\
k^{-1}\quad&\text{ if }\quad \alpha\leq k^{1/p}
\end{cases}
$$
So
$$
\alpha\mu(\{x\in[0,1]:f_{k,j}(x)>\alpha\})^{1/p}=
\begin{cases}
0\quad&\text{ if }\quad \alpha>k^{1/p}\\
\alpha k^{-1/p}\quad&\text{ if }\quad \alpha\leq k^{1/p}
\end{cases}
$$
Hence supremum is attained for $\alpha_0=k^{1/p}$ and now we conclude
$$
\sup\limits_{\alpha>0}\alpha\mu(\{x\in[0,1]:f_{k,j}(x)>\alpha\})^{1/p}=\alpha_0k^{-1/p}=1
$$

Comment: Thanks both to you and to David Mitra then!